# Get ASP.NET Web API Data in SSMS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, ssms

I'm working on a ASP.NET Web API project that uses default login and register functions and is connected to SQL Server.

Since the login and register functions work successfully, the registered data must be stored somewhere. Now my issue is I can't seem to get user data anywhere. The closest place I could found is SSMS, but there's no registered user data either.

I'm so new to this, so I don't know if it's possible to have access to user data. But if it is possible, what should I do to get the user data?

The default register page looks like(in Traditional Chinese):
[image]

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone to be able to assist you. Please make your question a [mre]

Comment: I've edited my question, hope this is easier to understand.

Comment: Can you please share more information about the Web API? If it is developed using Code First Approach then you need to make changes to your web.config by pointing towards your SSMS and do db migrations.
If possible, can you share the solution explorer screenshot?

Comment: What exectly are the "default login and register functions" please post some code. What tables are in the database reffered to by your program?

Answer (score 0):

First question are you using any connection string in  web.config. If not then do the following:
1. open cmd. and type this command "**sqllocaldb i**"
  I got the output like this:

```
MSSQLLocalDB
ProjectsV13
```

Now connect to the below 2 database engine:

```
(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB
(LocalDb)\ProjectsV13
```

If you find your database that's great.

If you are using a connection string then try connecting to the Data source of thee connection string and you can find the database there

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are working with ASP.Net membership provider. if So, you can see following tables or some tables having similar names in your database. if you are unable to find these tables then look at the connection strings at configuration file and find out relevant database name.

```
Application
Membership
Profiles
Roles
Users
UsersInRoles
```